# objective-c programming, (prepareForSegue)

Tags: objective-c

I try to make an iOS app, now I'm stack, I have a class as `book`, an as `bookdetailcontroller`, an as `simplebookmanager`, all working fine now I'm working on design, I already succeed to show the list of all books titles, now I try to click one title and show the other view about the books detail, when I click the detail views shows up but doesn't show any info, its empty! I show here my code:

this is a part of

```
//
//  SummaryMasterViewController.m
//  Design
//
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {

        SummaryDetailViewController *detailViewController = (SummaryDetailViewController *) [segue destinationViewController];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        detailViewController.book =[self.bookManager bookAtIndex: indexPath.row];
}


//
//  SummaryDetailViewController.h
//  Design

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "BookManagerProtocol.h"
#import "Book.h"
#import "SimpleBookManager.h"
#import "BookDetailViewController.h"

@interface SummaryDetailViewController : UIViewController <UISplitViewControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *detailDescriptionLabel;
@property Book *book;
@property BookDetailViewController *bookDetail;

@end
```

SummaryDetailViewController.m :

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitController `willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController`
{
    barButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Master", @"Master");
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem animated:YES];
    self.masterPopoverController = popoverController;
}
```

Comment: First: Does your app goes through the `if` in `prepareForSegue` ?
What's the code of `SummaryDetailViewController`?

Comment: yes, it does, I put the code above.

Comment: @implementation SummaryDetailViewController
#pragma mark - Managing the detail item
- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;
        [self configureView];}
    if (self.masterPopoverController != nil) {
        [self.masterPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];}        
}
- (void)configureView
{
    if (self.detailItem) {
        self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = [self.detailItem description];
    }
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self configureView];
}

Comment: Have you set any breakpoints? Is the segue identifier equal to showDetail? Is the `detailViewController` being set? When the second view appears are you able to log out book?